# React Hooks - useState value cannot change

Tags: reactjs, contenteditable, react-hooks

**Problem**

I want to get the `value` of the updated hooks state whenever I clicked **enter**.
But I always get the Initial Value, instead of the updated one.

**CODE**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ContentEditable from "react-contenteditable";

const ItemCol = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("Initial Value");

  const onChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    console.log("onChange: " + value);
  };

  const keyDown = event => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      //Value should be changed, but did not change
      console.log("Enter Pressed: " + value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ContentEditable
      html={value}
      onKeyDown={React.useCallback(keyDown)}
      onChange={React.useCallback(onChange)}
    />
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ItemCol />, rootElement);
```

CodeSandBox.io: https://codesandbox.io/embed/pensive-worker-31l3r

Note: keyCode 13 is Enter.

Note 2: I'm using react-contenteditable dependencies. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contenteditable)

Please do help me, as I have this problem for hours. Thanks !

Comment: setState is async. it will be updated in next render cycle.

Comment: How do I achieve that "next render cycle"? I get the changed value in onChange, but not in keyDown tho. Don't forget to check the Console log on the codesandbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ContentEditable component seems to memoize the `onKeydown` method and hence whenever you invoke it, it prints the value from its initial closure which is why you have the initial value always.

To solve this closure issue, you could keep the value in a ref and mutate it

```
const ItemCol = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("Initial Value");
  const valRef = useRef(value);
  const onChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    valRef.current = event.target.value;
  };

  const keyDown = event => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      //Value should be changed, but did not change
      console.log("Enter Pressed: " + valRef.current);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ContentEditable
      html={value}
      onKeyDown={keyDown}
      onChange={React.useCallback(onChange)}
    />
  );
};
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/pensive-worker-31l3r)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot..! This is all kinda new to me. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Harley,problem was with closure or with the way react-content-editable onkeydown function setup inside react-content-editable.

Working Demo:- https://codesandbox.io/embed/elated-bohr-jeu4u?fontsize=14

Resource :- https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/